# WordPress Plugin Development - How to Set a Locale

Tags: php, wordpress

I've scoured the internet in and out and I still do not understand how the translation functions work in combination with the .MO files. I understand that .MO files hold the translations to other languages, and that __() and _e() functions server as translators.

I have translated text in my plugin using `__('text', 'plugin-slug')` format.

I have created a .MO file for German translation but I'm not sure how it gets activated.

Do I have to develop an option in settings page where you can select the language of your choice.. if so, how do you pro grammatically force the plugin to use a certain language?

Or does wordpress automatically selects a plugin language based on the WordPress installation?

I am using the following code to load textdomain.

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'plugin-slug', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang/' );
```

It loads it correctly, as far as I'm concerned. The MO file within the `/lang/` folder is named `de_DE.mo`.

How do I go about it next? There's really not much information on this topic out there.. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or does wordpress automatically selects a plugin language based on the WordPress installation?

That's very much exactly what it does. You need to define the language in your config file (by defining `WPLANG`). WP picks it up from there and localizes strings the best it can according to your chosen locale.